# Why does SaK kill gdm, which is running on a different VT?

Tags: linux, gdm, magic-sysrq

I run Fedora Linux 28, and have enabled sysrq.  I pressed Alt+PrtScr+K, to kill a non-responsive X session.  But this also restarted `gdm`, and one other X session, which were running on different VTs.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Linux SaK kills all processes which have the current tty open.

   See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L2700
2. systemd-logind appears to open all active ttys.

   You can verify this using `lsof`.
3. When X is run as an unprivileged user and relies on systemd-logind, it does not handle a restart of systemd-logind.  When X loses its connection to systemd-logind, it terminates itself.

### Alternative

So SaK can indirectly affect all VTs, if you use unprivileged X, or Wayland.

Instead, you can use Alt+PrtScr+R, then Ctrl+Alt+F6.  You can log in on the text console, and manually kill processes e.g. `Xorg`, or `gnome-shell` if you use a GNOME Wayland session).